# django - CreateView to not create a model

Tags: django

I have a custom `create_user()` method that I use to create the user but I would like to shift to the `CreateView` view instead.

I need to supply some additional parameters before the user is created and need the *user object created to do some more processing (send an email) etc.*

How can I manipulate the object creation in CreateView. I can put my `create_user` method in the `form_valid` method of the view but what do I return then (`return super(UserCreate, self).form_valid(form)`) will create a new object.

```
class UserCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'crm2/create_user.html'
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'namespaces']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('crm2:userCreate')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = create_user(self.request.POST['username'],
                           self.request.POST['email'], str(uuid4()),
                           self.request.POST['namespaces'])
        reset_link = get_reset_link(user)
        send_mail_set_password(user, reset_link)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

[[ `create_user` needs `username`, `email`, `password`, `namespaces` ]]

The error is: `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: So, don't call super?

Comment: what do I return then?
I can manipulate the `form` to add some custom data and issue the `return super....`. Where do I do my preprocessing then?

Comment: You probably return your newly created user instance.

Comment: No, form_valid needs to return the HTTP response. Usually this is a redirect.

Comment: I can't do `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())` as well, for some reason

Comment: You *should* do `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())` instead of calling `super()`. Why can't you do that?

Comment: it says `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`
My relevant attribute is:
`success_url = reverse_lazy('crm2:userCreate')`

Comment: Show your view, the **full** traceback, and your url patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by looking at how `CreateView` works.

The incoming request is processed by the `post()` method of `ProcessFormView`, which calls `get_form_class()` and `get_form()`. This latter method deals with a POST request, so the code of `get_form_kwargs()` in FormMixin adds to the keywords dictionary the submitted data.

Now the form is bound (that is, it contains user supplied data or files) and the `post()` method now tests the result of is_valid() and acts accordingly calling either form_valid() or form_invalid().

The FormMixin class puts the result of `form.save()` into `self.object`. The `form.save()` method for modelforms is defined by `BaseModelForm` and basically saves the instance of the Django model connected with the modelform, that is implements the actual creation at the base of the `CreateView` form view. As `form.save()` returns the object saved to the database, it makes sense to store it in `self.object` and pass it to the template.

Hence,

```
class UserCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'crm2/create_user.html'
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'namespaces']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('crm2:userCreate')

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(UserCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = create_user(self.request.POST['username'],
                           self.request.POST['email'], str(uuid4()),
                           self.request.POST['namespaces'])
        reset_link = get_reset_link(self.object)
        send_mail_set_password(self.object, reset_link)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: You can remove your `get_form` method, it isn't doing anything different from the parent class. The key thing is that you need to set `self.object` so that `get_success_url()` works. That would have been clearer if you had posted the **full** traceback as I asked.

Comment: I need to edit the `get_form` method in the future, it's sort of a remainder, having it.

Comment: I just hit the same problem because I forgot to return the instance in the `ModelForm`subclass's `save()` method.